# How to make create Nomenclature List for SETA journal?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to figure out the exact format of creating a nomenclature list like the one shown in the picture below:

[image]

Here is a sample code I've been trying to tweak to meet the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
\item[\bfseries
\ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Abbreviations}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Symbols}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other symbols}{}}}%
]}
% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\nomenclature[A]{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
\nomenclature[A]{\(h\)}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature[A]{\(G\)}{Gravitational constant}
\nomenclature[S]{\(\mathbb{R}\)}{Real numbers}
\nomenclature[S]{\(\mathbb{C}\)}{Complex numbers}
\nomenclature[O]{\(\mathbb{H}\)}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[O]{\(V\)}{Constant volume}
\nomenclature[O]{\(\rho\)}{Friction index}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```